# Why is Crystal automatically adding Guidelines whenever I expand a section?

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm using Crystal 9, and whenever I add a new section to a report, and attempt to expand it, Crystal adds a BUNCH of horizontal guidelines.

It's *really* irritating. I figure there's got to be some setting I've tripped, but I can't figure out which one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer on Tek-Tips. Needed to set "Free Form Placement" in the File-> Options menu
[Link to Tek-Tips Discussion](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1657930&page=1)

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling guidelines in Design mode and see if that helps.  View | Guidelines | Design.

Not sure if it will work in v9, but selecting 'Fit section' will usually remove unnecessary ones.

** edit ** 
Position a field in the section of irritation at the vertical location that will preserve the section height, *then* to a 'fit section'.

Comment: Disabling them in design mode removes the "View" of the Guidelines, but the Guidelines are still there. The handles are still on the ruler (cluttering things up) and things will snap to the guidelines half the time.

Selecting "Fit To Section" removes the guidelines, but also shrinks the section... Regardless if I want it shrunk.

Comment: If I have a chance tomorrow, I'll see if I can find a registry key that controls this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and to solve it I just open File>Option and change the GridSize.  After this each time I added new section no Guidelines was added automatically.